# New install draws only desktop background (graphics driver issue)

Tags: drivers, graphics

I’ve installed Ubuntu 22.04 onto a PC I just built. I had to boot with `(safe graphics)` to get through the installation, and when the newly-installed OS booted, it had the same behavior as the installer: it boots to the desktop, but only draws the background image (a low-poly purple jellyfish).

I walked away to eat lunch, and when I came back, the display was asleep. Tapping some keys woke it up, but it was blurred. On a hunch, I typed my password. Sure enough, the desktop redrew unblurred.

So it seems just the UI elements are not rendering, implying a graphics issue. Unfortunately, I can’t seem to get back to a `(safe graphics)` reboot option. If I hold shift after resetting the machine, I get two choices: Ubuntu or Advanced Options. Avanced Options led me to a recovery mode option, which gave me another menu that included “resume,” but no “safe graphics” mode. I chose to resume, and held Shift down to try to get back to the original menu. But instead it booted into a safe graphics mode, characterized by a really low-resolution display with incorrect aspect ratio.

I need help sorting out the graphics driver, I think. The board is a standard version Axiomtek [MANO521](https://www.axiomtek.com/Default.aspx?MenuId=Products&FunctionId=ProductView&ItemId=25161&C=MANO521&upcat=136), with an Intel [i3-9100](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134870/intel-core-i39100-processor-6m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz.html) CPU with on-board graphics. The HDMI-connected display is a [UPERFECT](https://www.ebay.com/itm/394333664420) 2560x1440 that seems to be discontinued. But the Settings app shows “Unknown Display” and doesn’t let me change anything about it.

Is there a configuration I need to adjust, or a driver I need to install?

Some info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
$ sudo dmesg | head
[sudo] password for rmann: 
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.19.0-38-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-001) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #39~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Mar 17 21:16:15 UTC 2 (Ubuntu 5.19.0-38.39~22.04.1-generic 5.19.17)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-38-generic root=UUID=80c8659b-3034-4643-9b38-97eb4348a79b ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr

$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 2
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=800,600

$ sudo lspci -v
…
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel modules: i915
…
```

Comment: I updated the post with some additional information, but if there's something specific I can tell you let me know. I'm asking this question because I don't know what to look for or change.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, what I was seeing on the HDMI display was a secondary Ubuntu display. An internal but unconnected LVDS header on the MANO521 board was being used by Ubuntu as the primary display. Despite having moved the mouse around, I never saw the pointer.

The issue was solved by disabling the LVDS display in the BIOS Settings (Chipset tab -> System Agent Configuration -> Graphics Configuration -> LVDS Control -> Disabled):

[image: MANO521 BIOS Screenshot]

As a bonus, the external HDMI display backlight now actually turns off when the system sleeps the display.